# How to correctly mock a property of a mocked class?

Tags: c#, properties, mocking, moq

I was reviewing some unit tests from a colleague, and I saw something in the lines of:

```
var dogMock = new Mock<Dog>();

dogMock.Setup(d => d.Bark(It.IsAny<Volume>())).Returns(someMockedBarking);
dogMock.Object.Age = 2;
```

Is it ok that a property of the `Object` is directly set, or is it better to use the `Setup` and `Returns` like the following?

```
dogMock.Setup(d => d.Age).Returns(2);
```

In both cases, the unit tests succeeds though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. Note that the first one requires `SetupProperty` or `SetupAllProperties` to work correctly ([docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties)):

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
// mock.SetupProperty(f => f.Name);
// mock.SetupAllProperties();
IFoo foo = mock.Object;

foo.Name = "bar";
Assert.AreEqual("bar", foo.Name); // Throws if both commented out

public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also in some cases the `SetupProperty` approach can have advantages due it's  "tracking" behavior - if the mocked dependency has it's property heavily manipulated (multiple gets and sets are performed) it will allow easier setup and behaviour closer to "black box".

Comment: I didn't know that about mocking, thank you for your clear answer!
Edit: the unit test indeed had a call to ```SetupAllProperties()```, so everything makes sense now.